# Android ADB not working at all on macOS 10.15.5

Tags: android, macos, android-studio, usb, adb

I'm using MacBookPro Late 2018, previously running macOS 10.14 without any issues and I just upgrade to 10.15.5 by a clear installation (actually the mainboard got some issue and Apple changed the hardware and performed a clean install for me).

Now, I'm not able to use `adb` at all, no "USB icon" on the status bar on all my phones after USB is connected, instead, an error message `The connected device is unable to access data on this device. Reconnect the USB cable and try again.` appears, but **Android File Transfer works fine**.

I tried...

- 3 different USB cables (which all 3 are working previously)
- 3 different phones, Samsung Note 8 (An 9), Essential Phone PH-1 (An 10), Huawei P10 (An 8) which all 3 works well previously
- All USB mode on each phone
- Few different platform-tools version, including 27, 28, 30 (latest)
- Revoked all USB debugging authorizations
- All troubleshoot steps that I found on Google, i.e. `kill-server` or even the `adb_usb.ini`
- Remove all connected device from my MBP (even power supply), only my phone left
- Reset SMC by this instruction: https://support.apple.com/en-is/HT201295

What else I can try?

System Report:

[image: System Report]

Android Studio:

[image: Android Studio]

Attached is some message form `adb` cli:

```
> adb kill-server
adb D 06-12 13:58:03  1047 11576 adb_trace.cpp:187] Android Debug Bridge version 1.0.41
adb D 06-12 13:58:03  1047 11576 adb_trace.cpp:187] Version 30.0.2-6538114
adb D 06-12 13:58:03  1047 11576 adb_trace.cpp:187] Installed as /Users/xxx/Library/Android/sdk/platform-tools/adb
adb D 06-12 13:58:03  1047 11576 adb_trace.cpp:187]
adb D 06-12 13:58:03  1047 11576 adb_client.cpp:194] adb_kill_server
adb D 06-12 13:58:03  1047 11576 adb_io.cpp:107] writex: fd=3 len=13 30303039686f73743a6b696c6c 0009host:kill
adb D 06-12 13:58:03  1047 11576 adb_io.cpp:81] readx: fd=3 wanted=4
adb D 06-12 13:58:03  1047 11576 adb_io.cpp:97] readx: fd=3 wanted=4 got=4 4f4b4159 OKAY
```

```
> adb start-server
adb D 06-12 13:58:07  1048 11587 adb_trace.cpp:187] Android Debug Bridge version 1.0.41
adb D 06-12 13:58:07  1048 11587 adb_trace.cpp:187] Version 30.0.2-6538114
adb D 06-12 13:58:07  1048 11587 adb_trace.cpp:187] Installed as /Users/xxx/Library/Android/sdk/platform-tools/adb
adb D 06-12 13:58:07  1048 11587 adb_trace.cpp:187]
adb D 06-12 13:58:07  1048 11587 adb_client.cpp:346] adb_connect: service: host:start-server
adb D 06-12 13:58:07  1048 11587 adb_client.cpp:155] _adb_connect: host:version
* daemon not running; starting now at tcp:5037
adb D 06-12 13:58:07  1049 11589 adb_trace.cpp:187] Android Debug Bridge version 1.0.41
adb D 06-12 13:58:07  1049 11589 adb_trace.cpp:187] Version 30.0.2-6538114
adb D 06-12 13:58:07  1049 11589 adb_trace.cpp:187] Installed as /Users/xxx/Library/Android/sdk/platform-tools/adb
adb D 06-12 13:58:07  1049 11589 adb_trace.cpp:187]
* daemon started successfully
```

```
> adb devices
adb D 06-12 13:59:11  1067 12384 adb_trace.cpp:187] Android Debug Bridge version 1.0.41
adb D 06-12 13:59:11  1067 12384 adb_trace.cpp:187] Version 30.0.2-6538114
adb D 06-12 13:59:11  1067 12384 adb_trace.cpp:187] Installed as /Users/xxx/Library/Android/sdk/platform-tools/adb
adb D 06-12 13:59:11  1067 12384 adb_trace.cpp:187]
adb D 06-12 13:59:11  1067 12384 adb_client.cpp:155] _adb_connect: host:version
adb D 06-12 13:59:11  1067 12384 adb_io.cpp:107] writex: fd=3 len=16 30303063686f73743a76657273696f6e 000chost:version
adb D 06-12 13:59:11  1067 12384 adb_io.cpp:81] readx: fd=3 wanted=4
adb D 06-12 13:59:11  1067 12384 adb_io.cpp:97] readx: fd=3 wanted=4 got=4 4f4b4159 OKAY
adb D 06-12 13:59:11  1067 12384 adb_client.cpp:189] _adb_connect: return fd 3
adb D 06-12 13:59:11  1067 12384 adb_io.cpp:81] readx: fd=3 wanted=4
adb D 06-12 13:59:11  1067 12384 adb_io.cpp:97] readx: fd=3 wanted=4 got=4 30303034 0004
adb D 06-12 13:59:11  1067 12384 adb_io.cpp:81] readx: fd=3 wanted=4
adb D 06-12 13:59:11  1067 12384 adb_io.cpp:97] readx: fd=3 wanted=4 got=4 30303239 0029
List of devices attached
adb D 06-12 13:59:11  1067 12384 adb_client.cpp:387] adb_query: host:devices
adb D 06-12 13:59:11  1067 12384 adb_client.cpp:346] adb_connect: service: host:devices
adb D 06-12 13:59:11  1067 12384 adb_client.cpp:155] _adb_connect: host:devices
adb D 06-12 13:59:11  1067 12384 adb_io.cpp:107] writex: fd=3 len=16 30303063686f73743a64657669636573 000chost:devices
adb D 06-12 13:59:11  1067 12384 adb_io.cpp:81] readx: fd=3 wanted=4
adb D 06-12 13:59:11  1067 12384 adb_io.cpp:97] readx: fd=3 wanted=4 got=4 4f4b4159 OKAY
adb D 06-12 13:59:11  1067 12384 adb_client.cpp:189] _adb_connect: return fd 3
adb D 06-12 13:59:11  1067 12384 adb_client.cpp:364] adb_connect: return fd 3
adb D 06-12 13:59:11  1067 12384 adb_io.cpp:81] readx: fd=3 wanted=4
adb D 06-12 13:59:11  1067 12384 adb_io.cpp:97] readx: fd=3 wanted=4 got=4 30303030 0000
adb D 06-12 13:59:11  1067 12384 adb_io.cpp:81] readx: fd=3 wanted=0
adb D 06-12 13:59:11  1067 12384 adb_io.cpp:97] readx: fd=3 wanted=0 got=0
```

```
> adb usb
adb D 06-12 13:58:41  1052 11975 adb_trace.cpp:187] Android Debug Bridge version 1.0.41
adb D 06-12 13:58:41  1052 11975 adb_trace.cpp:187] Version 30.0.2-6538114
adb D 06-12 13:58:41  1052 11975 adb_trace.cpp:187] Installed as /Users/xxx/Library/Android/sdk/platform-tools/adb
adb D 06-12 13:58:41  1052 11975 adb_trace.cpp:187]
adb D 06-12 13:58:41  1052 11975 adb_client.cpp:346] adb_connect: service: usb:
adb D 06-12 13:58:41  1052 11975 adb_client.cpp:155] _adb_connect: host:version
adb D 06-12 13:58:41  1052 11975 adb_io.cpp:107] writex: fd=3 len=16 30303063686f73743a76657273696f6e 000chost:version
adb D 06-12 13:58:41  1052 11975 adb_io.cpp:81] readx: fd=3 wanted=4
adb D 06-12 13:58:41  1052 11975 adb_io.cpp:97] readx: fd=3 wanted=4 got=4 4f4b4159 OKAY
adb D 06-12 13:58:41  1052 11975 adb_client.cpp:189] _adb_connect: return fd 3
adb D 06-12 13:58:41  1052 11975 adb_io.cpp:81] readx: fd=3 wanted=4
adb D 06-12 13:58:41  1052 11975 adb_io.cpp:97] readx: fd=3 wanted=4 got=4 30303034 0004
adb D 06-12 13:58:41  1052 11975 adb_io.cpp:81] readx: fd=3 wanted=4
adb D 06-12 13:58:41  1052 11975 adb_io.cpp:97] readx: fd=3 wanted=4 got=4 30303239 0029
adb D 06-12 13:58:41  1052 11975 adb_client.cpp:155] _adb_connect: usb:
adb D 06-12 13:58:41  1052 11975 adb_io.cpp:107] writex: fd=3 len=18 30303065686f73743a74706f72743a61 000ehost:tport:a [truncated]
adb D 06-12 13:58:41  1052 11975 adb_client.cpp:114] Switch transport in progress: host:tport:any
adb D 06-12 13:58:41  1052 11975 adb_io.cpp:81] readx: fd=3 wanted=4
adb D 06-12 13:58:41  1052 11975 adb_io.cpp:97] readx: fd=3 wanted=4 got=4 4641494c FAIL
adb D 06-12 13:58:41  1052 11975 adb_io.cpp:81] readx: fd=3 wanted=4
adb D 06-12 13:58:41  1052 11975 adb_io.cpp:97] readx: fd=3 wanted=4 got=4 30303161 001a
adb D 06-12 13:58:41  1052 11975 adb_io.cpp:81] readx: fd=3 wanted=26
adb D 06-12 13:58:41  1052 11975 adb_io.cpp:97] readx: fd=3 wanted=26 got=26 6e6f20646576696365732f656d756c61 no devices/emula [truncated]
adb D 06-12 13:58:41  1052 11975 adb_client.cpp:117] Switch transport failed: no devices/emulators found
adb D 06-12 13:58:41  1052 11975 adb_client.cpp:360] _adb_connect error: no devices/emulators found
adb D 06-12 13:58:41  1052 11975 adb_client.cpp:364] adb_connect: return fd -1
error: no devices/emulators found
```